# Python pygmaps not resolving latitude and longitude to correct location on google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

If I use the following pygmaps code with Python 2.7 it does not resolve the latitude and longitude to the same location on google maps that entering 33°59'00.0"S 18°36'00.0"E into Google Maps does. Also the location is supposed to be Cape Town International Airport; so the pygmaps location seems to be wrong.

```
import pygmaps
mymap = pygmaps.maps(-33.59, 18.36, 14)
mymap.addpoint(-33.59, 18.36, '#0000FF')
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because pygmaps expects the latitude and longitude in decimal format, not in degrees and minutes.

So, the latitude shouldn't be `-33.59` -- it should actually be `-(33 + 59 / 60.0)`. Similarly, the longitude isn't `18.36` -- it should actually be `18 + 36 / 60.0`.

The latitude and longitude of Cape Town International Airport is approximately -33.983 and 18.600 in decimal format.